# git push to a new upstream branch

Tags: git

I have a repo that has not been associated with the repo I would like to push it to. After vetting, we are ready to submit it for comment at work.

first, I added the upstream repo I would like to push it to:

`git remote add upstream git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/place/projectgroup/repo`

This is the first and only upstream added, as before that it has lived only on my Mac. then I try to add the upstream:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/candidate/1.0
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/candidate/1.0' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
$ git push -u origin/candidate/1.0 HEAD
fatal: 'origin/candidate/1.0' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My question is, how do I push my current branch up to a remote repo using an upstream name that does not already exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you are on branch `mybranch`. Then you say

```
git push -u upstream mybranch
```

That means: "Take my local `mybranch`, push it up to the `upstream` remote (where it too will be called `mybranch`), and at the same time, give me a tracking branch that will act as a linkage between the local `mybranch` and the remote `mybranch`."

If you want the remote name to be different from the local name, use colon syntax, e.g. `mybranch:remotebranch`. (You might actually have to say `mybranch:refs/heads/remotebranch`, I'm a little confused about that.)

Comment: I am not on mybranch though.. I am on master. I need upstream to have a different name. I should bne able to do that directly, I believe. `git push -u upstream candidate/1.0
error: src refspec candidate/1.0 does not match any.`

Comment: that comment is the answer, please revise so I can accept